# What's the meaning of "low connectivity, authority lookup failed for too many validators"?

Tags: nodes, validator, networking

My validator node shows the issue "low connectivity, authority lookup failed for too many validators", what does this mean? And is it dangerous for the safety of the chain?

[image]

Comment: This is a warning letting you know that connectivity to validators is below the desired threshold. The PR for this is [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/3916).

Comment: I see, thanks, and I think the connected=2 means my validator was only connected with 2 other validators, right? But I also see the idle(5 peers) in the below. I used to think that means my validator was connected with 5 other validators, but now here is a connected=2. I was confused, so could you tell me what's the differences between them?

Comment: `connected=2` refers to connected peers who we know are authorities (according to the DHT records they've published). So there may be 5 peers but we do not necessarily know that they are authorities that is why you see `Idle (5 peers)`

Comment: I partly understand it now, thanks a lot.

Comment: @peilin I am aslo facing the same issue, can you help me with how you resolved it.